Partitioning new hard drive on a Dual boot
Just got a new hard drive and want to allocate some part to windows and the rest to Ubuntu both already installed on a single ssd before sometime ago. How do I go about this?

You've provided no clues as to what Ubuntu product/release you're using (Server with text terminal access only; Desktop with GUI etc) but partition the new drive as you want, then adjust the file-system table on your Ubuntu system so the created partition(s) are used as you wish; https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab

You can use gparted. Make sure drive is gpt and make est4 partition for Linux and NTFS for Windows/Linux. If larger drive I like to have an ESP - efi system partition and smaller /(root) partition as first partitions so I can have it as an emergency boot drive also. If I only add a few repair tools and use a lighter weight flavor, / does not have to be large although default install of snaps may require more now. I always remove snaps.

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.4, desktop with GUI @guiverc

@oldfred. I'll make sure to try this, thanks
